# dotnet ef not working after the latest SDK is updated

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

My system is:
Ubuntu 20.04.
zsh+ohmyzsh
terminator
kde

Recently when I wanted to run `dotnet-ef migrations add Add_Minor_Fields` I get:

```
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
```

Then if I do: `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef`

```
Tool 'dotnet-ef' is already installed.
```

What has changed since the last time I've run this:

1. Possibly the new patch versions of SDK and ef tools are release
2. I've installed KDE

What can be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

The location of dotnet gloabl tools should be in path

see: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools)

Linux/macOS:    `$HOME/.dotnet/tools`

Windows:    `%USERPROFILE%\.dotnet\tools`

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling dotnet-ef and then installing it.

Comment: It's not an answer, it should be a comment on the question.